# My sprite doesn't have a body, and game.physics.enable has no effect

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to enable the P2JS physics engine for a sprite in my game, and `game.physics.enable` only seems to work for the Arcade physics engine. What's going on here?

Example:

```
player.body
//=> null
game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.P2JS, true)
//=> undefined
player.body
//=> null
game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.NINJA, true)
//=> undefined
player.body
//=> null
game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE, true)
//=> undefined
player.body
//=> b.Physics.Arcade.Body {sprite: Player, game: b.Game, type: 0, offset: b.Point, position: b.Point…}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you started P2 running?

```
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);    
game.physics.p2.enable(sprite);
```

Also make sure you're using a version of Phaser with P2 bundled in it.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I knew I must have been missing something obvious like that.

Answer (score 2):

u should try this it will work

```
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
sprite.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;
game.physics.p2.enable(sprite);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer and the difference between it and the accepted answer, for example, why you set the `physicsBodyType`?

Comment: First line is enabling p2 system. Second line is setting the body type to p2 body type so it can use its methods(like collide etc). and the third line is to enable p2 on the sprite.